# A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'

Tags: android, react-native

While making build I am getting this issue

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> Task with path ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs' not found in project ':app'
```

**Package version**

```
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.2",
```

yesterday it was running fine and today it is causing the error. I uninstall and reinstall the package and also link it manually using **react-native link react-native-reanimated**  but still not working.

Answer (score 5):

I was using `react-native-reanimated` version `2.2.4` and after reading this [issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2412) I downgraded to `2.2.0` which was a quick win for my project. However a fix for the know issue has apparently been [merged here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/2564).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The project was working fine before, but after changing my PC and installed the dev env there, android studio gave this error. I had the project installed on mac machine, checked the node version of 2 environments. They were different. On windows, `node -v` was 16.12.0, on mac, it was 14.8.0

So, I uninstalled the current node.js from windows OS, then installed [older version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) of it.

After that, did `npm install` again, and gradle sync. It worked!

Hope this helps your problem.